# where should I define functions that i use in __init__

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a class that makes use of some functions inside its `__init__` function and I'm not sure about the best practice of where to define those functions. I usually like to define `__init__` first but if I need to use the a function/method within the `__init__` then it needs to be defined first. I dont want to define it outside the class as its useless outside the class but it seems messy to me to define methods before the `__init__`. What are the normal conventions for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add the methods to your class like every other method

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hi()

    def hi(self):
        print "Hi!"
```

No problem at all.

While it is not mentioned in the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) IIRC, it's convention to let `__init__` be the first method in your class.

Comment: Indeed, the point is that although the parser sees `__init__` before it sees the other methods, it doesn't _run_ it until the class has been fully defined, at which point the other methods are available.

Answer (score 4):

The normal convention is indeed to put `__init__` before other methods. The reason this works is that functions aren't evaluated until invoked. From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> A function definition is an executable statement. Its execution binds the function name in the current local namespace to a function object (a wrapper around the executable code for the function). This function object contains a reference to the current global namespace as the global namespace to be used when the function is called.
>
> The function definition does not execute the function body; this gets executed only when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to define `__init__` function as first function, and you can call functions defined after `__init__` inside it.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print self.x()

    def x(self):
        return 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be 'messy' to define methods after the init ? Think about it that way :

When you define

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.something = whatever
        self.do_something_else()

    def do_something_else(self):
        ...
```

`__init__` is a method of your `MyClass` class, just like `do_something` is; it's just the *first* method of the class that will be called when you create an instance of `MyClass`. So, putting `__init__` first is not only customary but also logical.

Your `do_something_else` method doesn't have to be defined first because you use it in `__init__`. From the point of view of `MyClass`, it's a method like another. When you create your `myclass=MyClass()` instance, `do_something_else` has already been defined...